# How to fix when Python says: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'money' referenced before assignment

Tags: variables, python-3.x, addition

I am having troubles with my money variable. Each time I save and run, a ERROR pops up and I try to fix the problem but can't figure out how? I really need a reply so please soon. This is my project:

```
   money = 0.0
Chop = 0
spike = 0
name = input("What is your name?")
greeting = 'Hello ' + name + ','

def Command():
    Command = input('Press \"C\" to continue or Press \"E\" to exit -->')

if name == 'SpikeTheKing':
print('Welcome Spike,')
spike = 1
elif name == 'Spike':
spike = 1
print ('Welcome Spike,')
else:
print(greeting)
def draw_line():
print ('----------------')


def Work1():
Chop = input('Type anything to earn $1 -->')
while Chop == ('C') or ('c'):
    print ('$1 earned')
    money = money+1
    displayMoney()
    Chop = 0
    Command()
def displayMoney():
draw_line()
print(('Money = '),('$'),(money))
draw_line()
displayMoney()
Work1()
 if Command == ('C'):
 Work1()
 if Command == ('E'):
 quit()
```

Each time I save and run this happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Leora\Desktop\Python Files\Python.py", line 35, in <module>
Work1()
File "C:\Users\Leora\Desktop\Python Files\Python.py", line 26, in Work1
money = money+1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'money' referenced before assignment
```

What should I change?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the `def Work` code, before you do `money = money+1`, you will need to initialize `money`. So in the first statement after `def Work`, do: `money = 0`...

Alternatively, money is `global` , so you could do `global money`, in the first line after `def Work` instead of `money=0`....

The `global` keyword tells the interpreter, that `money` is defined outside the scope of `Work` function and to look for it there